# How can I link to the results of a Jira JQL query?

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way in Jira's JQL to link to the results of a jql query directly?  I don't mind if the link is long and nasty (some of my jql queries are themselves), but I want to be able to build something that looks like:

```
https://myJiraHost/jira/secure/jqlQuery?query=myEncodedJQLQuery
```

Thus I could email this link and have anyone who can login to Jira can see the results of this query with one click.  If this isn't available, does anyone know if Attlasian is working on something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the Permalink function on the Issue Navigator work? https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+the+Issue+Navigator

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the url in the browser of your search and share it.

Note the search shall not be saved as a filter if you want to share ad-hoc (without sharing the filter)

The url looks something like: $YourJiraRootUrl/issues?jql=$encoded Jql